# Intercept default method of the interface with returning value

Tags: java, spring, aop

I would like to intercept method after returning a value.

The method is the default method on the interface and I would like to have returning value of the default intf implementation and also overriding implementation in the concrete class.

this is my aspect:

```
@Aspect
@Configuration
public class ResAspect {

    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "within(org.my.app.Strategy+) && execution(* shouldEnter(..))", returning = "res")
    public void shouldOperate(JoinPoint jp, boolean res) {
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

this is the default method:

```
    default boolean shouldEnter(int i, Rec r) {
        return !evaluate(i, r);
    }
```

as you can guess it's not working. So can I achieve what I want with Spring AOP?

Can I access the implementing class instance and it's properties within the aspect?

**EDIT:** the interface I want to intercept is located in another module

Comment: For your first question, do you want to access the results of both the default method in the interface and its overridden version? If so, the only way I can think of is using @Around to intercept the call, get the target object then call the super method and get its result (I haven't tried this but I think it should work) then proceed and get the result of the overridden version.

Comment: let's say just the default intf implementation for now

Comment: For me this works like in your example out of the box. You must have a configuration issue. So please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), something I can compile and run, either here by editing your question or by providing a link to a GitHub repository.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the instance on which the method is invoked, aka the target, inside the advice as follows:

```
YourInterface interfaceReference = (YourInterface) joinPoint.getTarget();
```

You can then access whatever you want using the retrieved object.